# Display the isolation level

Tags: sap-ase, isolation-level

Is it possible to display the current isolation config set in Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise 12.5.4?

If so, then how can I display it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try select from `@@isolation` variable :

```
select @@isolation
```

You can also read [this](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20021_1251/html/locking/locking86.htm). It says:

```
The current isolation level for a session 
can be determined with the global variable @@isolation.
```